# Language detection by domain breaks ajax requests over https

Tags: 8, ajax, domain-access, subsites

What do I have:

- Drupal 8.6.2
- [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain/)
- Language modules
- Cloudflare with https

Problem:

If in URL language detection option (**/admin/config/regional/language/detection/url**) I have "**Path prefix**" - everything works fine.

Party starts, when I change it to "**Domain**" - ***every ajax request on any subdomain is trying to get through http instead of https*** and I can see "**mixed content error**" in console, so these requests are being blocked and website is malfunctioning. I cant use views propeerly, upload files through Plupload, use autocomplete forms, change some settings etc.

If I change it back to prefix - ajax works great again.

For prefix I have **site.com** for default language and **site.com/en** - for english. For domain setting: **site.com** - default and **en.site.com** is english version.

In Domain Access settings I've tried to set all possible URL schemas (http, https and variable) - no change. In Cloudflare settings I have speacial rules, redirecting every request from http to https (*I set up CF's https for dozen of websites, I know how to do it*).

If I set back to **prefix** and go to **en.site.com** (*it still works as an alias for the main domain*) ajax works fine, so this is not something about server or background settings - it's just Drupal messing around.

I could run it with prefix, but for SEO purposes it is better to use subdomain, because website is going to be big and it is better to separate languages technically on different websites, search engines will rank these subdomains more correct.

Please help! This is my first experience with multilingual website and I don't have a clue what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after hours of searching the web, googling, asking... here is the solution.

1) Go to **ISP panel** > Web-server settings > SSL Sertificates > add self signed sertificate for your domain.

2) While in ISP, go to **WWW-domains** and double click on your domain > check **Secure connection (SSL)**, SSL port - 443, select your sertificate from dropdown list and save.

3) Then go to Cloudflare domain settings, open **Crypto** page and change SSL from Flexible to **Full**.

Thats it! As simple as that. And there is no need in reverse proxy in settings.php

Comment: Yes, this is best solution, if you can setup a secure connection between CDN and Drupal. Though you might still want to configure the CDN in settings.php to get the correct client IP.

Comment: @4k4 I've installed Cloudflare module for this (https://www.drupal.org/project/cloudflare)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the CDN, which connects to Drupal via HTTP and to the client via HTTPS. Then all absolute URLs generated by Drupal have the wrong protocol. Not only this one for ajax, which is absolute because you've switched language detection to domain based. Prefix based it uses relative paths and then the protocol doesn't matter.

Normally CDN's add a header `X_FORWARDED_PROTO` to the request, which Drupal can use to determine the correct protocol. For this to work you have to configure the CDN as reverse proxy in settings.php.

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong. In settings.php I've enabled $settings['reverse_proxy'] by setting it ti TRUE and uncommenting the rest: $settings['reverse_proxy_addresses'] (added all known cloudflare's ip addresses), $settings['reverse_proxy_proto_header'] = 'X_FORWARDED_PROTO'; and $settings['omit_vary_cookie'] = TRUE;

But stil doesn't work.

Comment: I've answered to explain how the ajax behavior might be connected to the CDN setup. For the latter see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199722/how-to-correctly-configure-settings-php-to-use-reverse-proxy-and-ssl-termination

Comment: I've checked $_SERVER output and it shows, that X_FORWARDED_PROTO is set to http, as well as REQUEST_SCHEME. Enabling or disabling ['reverse_proxy'] in settings.php does nothing.

Comment: Then this is probably an issue with the CDN configuration to get the correct client protocol into X_FORWARDED_PROTO.

Comment: The only place I found https mentioned is here: [HTTP_CF_VISITOR] => {"scheme":"https"}. But I don't think, that I can use this cloudflare header somehow in Drupal. Maybe I need to configure my web server somehow? Because I did nothing in server config.